# Load each character of a string into a register

Tags: assembly, mips

So I am trying to push each character of a user input string into a stack using MIPS.  I load the string into memory and try to iterate through it, saving each character one by one into a register then pushing that register into the stack.  My problem is this:

The loop I have set up to save each character into a register will load the first character no problem, but then it will start to load characters not in the string.  If the user inputs "lol" as the string, the program will load 108 (the ascii code for lowercase l) on the first loop, but on the next go around it will load 105 (lowercase i), then it will load 79 (uppercase O), etc...  Here is the loop I have been using:

```
.text

main:

li $v0, 4                       # Prints str1
la $a0, str1
syscall

jal Init                        # Sets $s0 equal to $sp to compare if the stack is empty later

li $v0, 8                       # Read String
la $a0, buffer                  # Loads memory buffer (100)
li $a1, 100                     # Defines length of buffer
syscall

la $t0, buffer                  # Moves base register to $t0

PushLoop:   
    lb $a2, 0($t0)              # Loads current character into $a2
    beq $a2, 0, fin             # if $a2 is equal to ascii code 10, the loop is terminated
    jal Push                    # Pushes what is stored in $a0 to the stack
    add $t0, $t0, -8            # Subtracts from buffer 
    j PushLoop

fin:
    la $t0, buffer              # Resets the memory buffer

 Push:
    addi $sp, $sp, -1           # Move stack pointer
    sb $a2, ($sp)               # Store contents of $a2 at ($sp)
    jr $ra
```

I should also mention this is a follow up question from this: [Push Each Character of a String Into a Stack MIPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28887686/push-each-character-of-a-string-into-a-stack-mips)

Comment: Why are you subtracting `8` from `$t0`? I would expect you want to add `1` instead. PS: learn to use your debugger/simulator.

Comment: Okay, that seems to help!  There are more errors in my code, but I'll figure them out one by one.  And I apologize if it was a stupid question, I'm rather new to assembly code and am still learning.  I thought a character took up 8 bites of space, that's why I had the 8 there.

Comment: It takes up 8 bits, but that's just 1 byte. Still doesn't explain why you were counting down instead of up, though ;)

Comment: Ah, that makes sense!  Thank you for helping me out!  I still have much to learn.

Comment: Note that the stack grows **downwards**, and your pointer needs to go **upwards** in memory.